# Why is `alsactl store` not enough to persist sound levels?

Tags: sound, alsa

My sound levels in `alsamixer`, e.g. `Mic boost` are not saved after restarting.

Many people tell to use `sudo alsactl store` to save those levels, but that has never worked for me in any machine I own.

In fact, using `sudo alsactl restore` in the terminal after booting does indeed set the levels, but calling that command in `/etc/rc.local` does not solve the issue. Is Ubuntu resetting these levels somehow during boot?

Comment: You say store has never worked, yet restore manages to restore the levels? How is that possible?

Comment: @muru Maybe something overwrites them later and sets the Mic Boost to zero. But I don't know what could it be.

Comment: In /etc/rc.local , try to remove sudo to keep only `alsactl restore` (not tested ). Is your soundcard the first?  (if it is the 2nd which means that you must type F6 in alsamixer to select it, then the command is `sudo alsactl store 1 `

Comment: Strangely, *some* controls are persisted without even issuing an `alsactl store`. For instance, `Mic` is persisted, but `Mic Boost` is not.

Comment: With regard to the first suggestion, I was not using `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local` since it already runs as root. My card is the first (0 index). I tried specifying the index, just in case, to no effect.